# How can I get the Duplicate key value pair of an HashMap?

Tags: java, hashmap

```
HashMap<Integer,Integer> hashmapsample= new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
```

I can have values like

```
(1 , 7)
(2 , 4)
(4 , 5)
(3,  7)
```

There wont be any duplicate Keys . Only Duplicate values can occur

I want to pick the (Key,Value) pair which has duplicate values.

If I get the Duplicate (Key,Value) as another  Hashmap it would be great.
How Do I go about it.?

I expect the output

```
 (1 , 7)
 (3,  7)
```

Comment: didn't get it clearly, could you post with an example

Comment: @ Meenakshi: from the above example do you want (1,7) and (3,7) as the duplicate values are there?

Comment: As (3, 7) has duplicate value 7 he wants this pair (3, 7) in another hashmap. I think so

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about this?

```
public HashMap getDuplicateValues(HashMap in)
{
   // Clone input HashMap because we're removing stuff from it
   in = (HashMap)in.clone();
   HashMap rval = new HashMap();
   Object[] keys = in.keySet().toArray();

   // iterate through all keys
   for(int x=0;x<keys.length;x++) {
      Object value = in.get(keys[x]);
      in.remove(keys[x]);
      // if value is in input HashMap, store it in duplicate HashMap because it has another value
      if(in.containsValue(value)) {
         rval.put(keys[x],value);
      }
      // if value is in duplicate HashMap, store it also because it HAD another value earlier
      if(rval.containsValue(value)) {
         rval.put(keys[x],value);
      }
   }

   return(rval);
}
```

This method will return key/value pairs for all the duplicate values in the input HashMap.

---

Test code:

```
  HashMap map = new HashMap();

  map.put("1","2");
  map.put("2","1");
  map.put("3","8");
  map.put("4","4");
  map.put("5","6");
  map.put("6","8");
  map.put("7","3");
  map.put("8","4");
  map.put("9","4");

  HashMap dups = getDuplicateValues(map);

  System.out.println("MAP = "+map);
  System.out.println("DUP = "+dups);
```

Output:

```
MAP = {3=8, 2=1, 1=2, 7=3, 6=8, 5=6, 4=4, 9=4, 8=4}
DUP = {3=8, 6=8, 4=4, 9=4, 8=4}
```

Comment: @Meenakshi try this Code it Works.

Answer (score 1):

You can not have duplicate keys. Think of it like a bunch of boxes, with spots in them for **one** thing each. You can put a hammer in box 1, a keyboard in box 2, a flashlight in box 3, and another hammer in box 4. However, you can't put two hammers or a hammer and a keyboard in box 1, as it only has room for a single thing. If you try to add another thing into an already full box, it will automatically take it out, and discard the old thing. There is no way then to access it

I think I may have misinterpreted this question though; could you explain better what exactly  your trying to retrieve/do?

Ok, here's some code to essentially reverse your HashMap:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    HashMap start = new HashMap();
    start.put(1, 7);
    start.put(2, 4);
    start.put(4, 5);
    start.put(3, 7);

    HashMap<Object, ArrayList<Object>>  reversed = reverse(start);

    //Some code to print out our results
    Set<Entry<Object, ArrayList<Object>>> set = reversed.entrySet();

    for(Entry entry : set) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ": " + entry.getValue());
        //if we want here, we can check if the size of the value (The 
    //ArrayList of old keys who has a value of this guy's key) is over 1, if so,
    //there were duplicates of some value (stored to this entry's key)
    }
}
public static HashMap<Object, ArrayList<Object>> reverse(HashMap map) {
    HashMap<Object, ArrayList<Object>> newMap = 
            new HashMap<Object, ArrayList<Object>>();

    Set<Entry> set = map.entrySet();
    for(Entry entry : set) {
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
        if(newMap.containsKey(entry.getValue())) {
            list=newMap.get(entry.getValue());
        }
        list.add(entry.getKey());
        newMap.put(entry.getValue(), list);
    }
    return newMap;
}
```

Comment: I just made a statement So that its clear , that when I mean duplicate it means for a value and not for the Keys .

Answer (score 1):

```
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> sample = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    Integer valueForSearch = 7;
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> result = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    for (Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : sample.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getValue().equals(valueForSearch)) {
            result.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is not a generic code. It would only find out if value is 7

Comment: @Jin35 I might not know that 7 only occurs twice . There could be 5 occuring 3 times or there might be some other values more than once.

Comment: Yep, but if you want get **all** duplicates result will be `HashMap<value, HashMap<key,value>>`.

Answer (score 0):

Just to give the outline...

```
  Object array[] = hashmapsample.keySet().toArray();
  for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++)
  {
         if(hashmapsample.containsValue(hashmapsample.get(array[i]){
    //Put that particular value in another hashmap here
    }     
  }
```

Ahh.. I could find much detailed answers in this post :D Ignore mine then..